# How do I combine IQueryables into a single call?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'd like to pass `IQueryable` as a parameter to a function that would then call the Entity Framework provider to execute a query as follows:

```
public ICollection<MyRowType> RunCommand(IQueryable<MyRowType> query)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var result = db.MyRowType
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableA)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableB)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableC)

            // How do I make the value in `query` run here?

            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm basically wrapping my database calls to this method to return all the necessary includes but I don't want to lose the flexibility of making custom queries via `IQueryable<MyRowType>`.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
public ICollection<MyRowType> SomeOtherMethod(string id, SomeValue value = null, SomeOtherValue  otherValue = null)
{
    var query = Enumerable.Empty<MyRowType>()
        .Where(r => r.Id == di);

    if (value != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyOne == value);

    if (otherValue != null)
        query = query.Where(r => r.PropertyTwo == otherValue);

    return RunCommand(query);     
}
```

Answer update:

I combined the answers of [Yacoub Massad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970242/160823) and [dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970378/160823) into these two methods:

```
public static ICollection<MyRowType> RunCommand(Expression<Func<MyRowType, bool>> condition)
{
    return Get(t => t.Where(condition));
}

public static ICollection<MyRowType> RunCommand(Func<IQueryable<MyRowType>, IQueryable<MyRowType>> query)
{
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        var includes = db.MyRowType
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableA)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableB)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableC)

        var result = query(includes)
            .ToList();

       return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a query that you would like to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `Func<IQueryable<MyRowType>,IQueryable<MyRowType>>` instead of `IQueryable<MyRowType>` like this:

```
public ICollection<MyRowType> RunCommand(Func<IQueryable<MyRowType>,IQueryable<MyRowType>> func)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<MyRowType> q = db.MyRowType
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableA)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableB)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableC);

        var result = func(q);

        return result.List();
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
var result = RunCommand(q => q.Where(....));
```

Or use other LINQ methods like this:

```
var result = RunCommand(q => q.Where(....).OrderBy(x => ...).Take(10));
```

Please note that you cannot pass a query that will select a different type than `MyRowType`. If you want that then you can make the method generic like this:

```
public ICollection<T> RunCommand<T>(Func<IQueryable<MyRowType>,IQueryable<T>> func)
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<MyRowType> q = db.MyRowType
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableA)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableB)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableC);

        var result = func(q);

        return result.List();
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
var result = RunCommand<SomeOtherType>(q => q.Where(x => ....).Select(x => ....));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to extract the expression from `IQueryable<T>`, and you wouldn't be able to apply the `queryable` that you pass into the method directly. However, since it appears that you are trying to limit the query by passing `IQueryable<T>` without changing the output type, it may be easier to change the API to take a condition instead of `IQueryable<T>`, like this:

```
public ICollection<MyRowType> RunCommand(Expression<Func<MyRowType,bool>> condition) {
    using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
        var result = db.MyRowType
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableA)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableB)
            .Include(r => r.RelatedTableC)
            .Where(condition)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

If you use [*LINQ to Entities predicate combiner*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx) you would be able to combine your custom conditions with the common preparation steps performed inside your `RunCommand` method:

```
public ICollection<MyRowType> SomeOtherMethod(string id, SomeValue value = null, SomeOtherValue  otherValue = null) {
    Expression<Func<MyRowType,bool>> condition =
        r => r => r.Id == di;
    if (value != null)
        condition = condition.And(r => r.PropertyOne == value);
    if (otherValue != null)
        condition = condition.And(r => r.PropertyTwo == otherValue);
    return RunCommand(query);     
}
```

Comment: I have an overload of the method that takes a condition as you outlined. I'm looking to be able to pass along things like `FirstOrDefault` or multiple `Where` clauses constructed on their own. On a side note, your example helped me solve a problem where if I pass a `Func<MyRowType,bool>` it executes the condition after hitting the database, much appreciated.

Comment: You're correct about FirstOrDefault, I want to give other methods the ability to construct the IQueryable based on their own logic. I'll add an example to my question.

Comment: @Omar You should be able to fit your example (with multiple `Where` clauses) into the `Expression<Func<MyRowType,bool>>` approach.